# Angular - ng-content with params

Tags: angular

I will really appreicate help with following scenario.

I have spa project build with angular 4. within this project I have a order page where user can order a new translation for his videos.
Firstly, user choose the video source language and the desired target language. 
After user choose the order details , user can upload one ore more video for translation.

In order to upload videos I wrote a video-uploader component where all the uploaded videos are displayed as rows with basic information like (duration,title,frameRate etc).
Now I want to add to each video row a price field. the problem is that the price is related to the source and target language (each source-target language combination has a different price per second).

So what is my problem ?
I don't want to pass video-uploader component a from and to language property, nor do I want to send ita pricePerSecond property. I really want video uploader component to do what it should to.

I thought about using transclude with a video-details like this this

```js
//From order component
<video-uploader>
  <video-details [from]="from" [to]="to">
</video-uplaoder>

//From video-uploader - something like thath
<ng-content *ngFor="let video of videos" [video]="video"/>
```

The problem is that although [from] and [to] should be set from order component 
the [video] data should be set by the video-uploader.component

Is it possible to achive the desired behaviour ?

Comment: `<ng-content>` only supports the `select` attribute and only with static values. `*ngFor` and `[video]="video"` are meaningless on `<ng-content>`. I don't get what you try to accomplish to make alternative suggestions.

Comment: You should try to learn about transclusion  before using it. Check this https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content and this https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content

Comment: I will try to explain it better.
Lets say I have video-uploader where a user can upload videos.